# apache-flume-1.5.2 is compatible with hadoop-2.5.1 or not?

Tags: flume, hadoop2

I am new to Apache Flume and I am trying to perform PoC with Apache Flume & Hadoop, but I don't know which version will be suitable for this exercise.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested Flume with several versions of Hadoop and always worked. The official Apache Flume documentation does not specify any required Hadoop version in its [HDFS Sink](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink) so I guess it is using some Hadoop API that has not chenged over time (which is really good). Let's do the exercise of going into the details:

The [`HDFSWriterFactory`](https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/542b1695033d330eb00ae81713fdc838b88332b6/flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/HDFSWriterFactory.java) class used by [`HDFSEventSink.process()`](https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/542b1695033d330eb00ae81713fdc838b88332b6/flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/HDFSEventSink.java) to get a HDFS writer may provide a:

- [`HDFSSequenceFile`](https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/542b1695033d330eb00ae81713fdc838b88332b6/flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/HDFSSequenceFile.java): it uses a `org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile` in order to write the data.
- [`HDFSDataStream`](https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/542b1695033d330eb00ae81713fdc838b88332b6/flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/HDFSDataStream.java): it uses a `org.apache.flume.serialization.EventSerializer`.
- [`HDFSCompressedDataStream`](https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/542b1695033d330eb00ae81713fdc838b88332b6/flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/HDFSCompressedDataStream.java): again, it uses a `org.apache.flume.serialization.EventSerializer`.

On the one hand, [`org.apache.hadoop.io.EventSerializer`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile.java) is quite large and seems to maintain a lot of deprecated methods for writing the data, so that could explain the compatibility with *all* Hadoop versions. On the other hand, [`org.apache.flume.serialization.EventSerializer`](https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/542b1695033d330eb00ae81713fdc838b88332b6/flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/serialization/EventSerializer.java) uses standard `java.io.OutputStream`, which I think is quite stable.